# systemd timer every 2 hours at 30 minutes past the hour?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

There are several good references on `systemd` timers including this one:

[`systemd.time`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html)

Unfortunately, it still isn't clear to me how to create a timer that will run periodically, but at a specific number of minutes after the top of the hour.

I want to create a timer that runs 30 minutes past the hour, every 2 hours. So it would run at 14:30 (2:30 pm), 16:30, 18:30, 20:30, etc.

I tried several things that did not work, including this:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* *00/2:30
```

And this:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00/2:30
```

I did not find the time specification to produce the desired result.

Also, it does not have to run exactly at that moment, so I was thinking about using:

```
AccuracySec=5m
```

Comment: You should use `RandomizedDelaySec=5m` instead of `AccuracySec` for the purpose.

Comment: Edit: not available on systemd-analyze 219. Need to [upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609730/390092)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Every 2 hours at 30 minutes past the hour should be

```
OnCalendar=00/2:30
#   iow    hh/r:mm
```

`00/2` - the `hh` value is `00` and the repetition value `r` is `2` which means the `hh` value plus all multiples of the repetition value will be matched (`00`,`02`,`04`..`14`,`16`..etc)
`30` - the `mm` value, `30` will match 30 minutes past each hour

I left the date and the seconds out since, per the same `man` page:

> date specification may be omitted, in which case the current day [...] is implied [...]If the second component is not specified, ":00" is assumed.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I am still trying to digest the systemd timer grammar... Would every 4 hours be `OnCalendar=00/4:00`?

Comment: @jww - that is correct. As to your other Q - try to specify `Unit=ftc-data.service` under `[Timer]` before (or after) `OnCalendar`... And btw, you don't enable the service, only the timer.

Comment: Thanks @don. `Unit=ftc-data.service` did not help. Does `crontab` still work on new Fedora systems? I'm happy use it to avoid dicking around with systemd problems.

Answer (score 9):

Solution for for future readers:

```
    # systemd-analyze calendar --iterations=2 '0/2:30:00'            
      Original form: 0/2:30:00
    Normalized form: *-*-* 00/2:30:00
        Next elapse: Fri 2023-01-20 16:30:00 EET
           (in UTC): Fri 2023-01-20 14:30:00 UTC
           From now: 1h 22min left
           Iter. #2: Fri 2023-01-20 18:30:00 EET
           (in UTC): Fri 2023-01-20 16:30:00 UTC
           From now: 3h 22min left
```

Comment: This just repeats the solution given in the accepted answer.

Comment: But it’s much clearer

Comment: After searching for a moment, I found this helpfull command "systemd-analyze calendar" ! Thx +1