# Can't Start Systemd Timer

Tags: centos, systemd

I have the following systemd timer configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for Service

[Timer]
Unit=service-unit.service
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:0,15,30,45:00
# *-*-* means every day and 10:00:00 is the time of day (UTC)

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

When attempting to start the timer I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23...5,30,45:00 service-timer.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
```

I tried checking the timestamp with `systemd-analyze calendar "Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:5,30,45:00"` but my version does not seem to have this option. It returns `Unknown operation 'calendar'.`

When attempting on a different server where the calendar option is available it seems to be a valid timestamp.

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze calendar "Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:0,15,30,45:00"

  Original form: Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:0,15,30,45:00
Normalized form: Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:00,15,30,45:00
    Next elapse: Thu 2020-09-10 14:00:00 EDT
       (in UTC): Thu 2020-09-10 18:00:00 UTC
       From now: 1min 21s left
```

The server where it is not working is CentOS 7 and the server where it is working is Ubuntu 18.04 Minimal.

Comment: What version of systemd is installed in CentOS 7? What options does `systemd-analyze --help` show?

Comment: @ajgringo619 systemctl --version outputs: systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

The options for systemd-analyze are time, blame, critical-chain, plot, do, set-log-level, dump, and verify.

Comment: That's pretty old; Ubuntu 18.04 uses v237. You'll need to look at the man pages for **systemd.time** and **systemd.timer** to find the difference(s) and adjust your timer as necessary. I don't have any systems that old so I can't be of further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who answered. For me, the best option was to update systemd using a backport from Facebook that I found [here](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jsynacek/systemd-backports-for-centos-7/). This way I can take advantage of newer features rather than use workarounds.

After updating from 219 to 231 it worked without issue. The basic update instructions provided in that repo are as follows:

> #### Installation Instructions
>
> 1. Make sure to edit /etc/selinux/config and put SELinux to permissive before you update, otherwise your system will not boot
>    anymore!
> 2. `# wget https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/jsynacek/systemd-backports-for-centos-7/repo/epel-7/jsynacek-systemd-backports-for-centos-7-epel-7.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jsynacek-systemd-centos-7.repo`
> 3. `# yum update systemd`
> 4. Reboot.

Answer (score 3):

The version of systemd available on CentOS 7 doesn’t support spans defined with `..`. `13..23` can be expressed as `13/1` (hours starting at 13 and then every hour), but I think `Mon..Fri` can only be expressed as the list of days, thus

```
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-* 13..23:0,15,30,45:00
```

becomes

```
OnCalendar=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri *-*-* 13/1:0,15,30,45:00
```